# Upload Large files(1GB)-ASP.net

Tags: c#, .net

I need to upload large files of at least `1GB` file size.
I am using `ASP.Net`, `C#` and `IIS 5.1` as my development platform.

I am using:

```
HIF.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(fileBytes,0,HIF.PostedFile.ContentLength)
```

before using:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileByteArray)
```

(doesnt go here but gives `System.OutOfMemoryException` exception)

Currently I have set the `httpRuntime` to:

> executionTimeout="**999999**" maxRequestLength="**2097151**"(thats 2GB!)
>       useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
>       appRequestQueueLimit="5000" enableVersionHeader="true" requestLengthDiskThreshold="8192"

Also i have set `maxAllowedContentLength="**2097151**"` (guess its only for IIS7)

I have changed `IIS` connection timeout to 999,999 secs too.

I am unable to upload files of even `4578KB` (Ajaz-Uploader.zip)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Large file doesn't upload in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071798/large-file-doesnt-upload-in-asp-net)

Comment: what .net version are you using ?

Answer (score 10):

We have an app that occasionally needs to upload 1 and 2 GB files, so has been running into this as well. After much research, my conclusion is that we need to implement the previously mentioned [NeatUpload](https://github.com/joeaudette/neatupload), or something like it.

Also, be aware that

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength=.../>
```

is measured in **bytes**, while

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength=.../>
```

is measured in **kilobytes**. So your values should look more like this:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151"/>
...
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2097151000"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

I googled and found - [NeatUpload](https://github.com/joeaudette/neatupload)

---

Another solution would be to read the bytes on the client and send it to the server, the server saves the file.
Example

Server: in Namespace - Uploader, class - Upload

```
[WebMethod]
public bool Write(String fileName, Byte[] data)
{
    FileStream  fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open);
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs); 
    bw.Write(data);
    bw.Close();

    return true;
}
```

Client:

```
string filename = "C:\..\file.abc";
Uploader.Upload up = new Uploader.Upload();
FileStream  fs = File.Create(fileName); 
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

// Read all the bytes
Byte[] data = br.ReadBytes();
up.Write(filename,data);
```

Comment: I haven't checked the code. Not sure this works, just wanted to convey the idea. This is nearly what FTP does, except that instead of port 20/21, everything is happening over port 80.

Comment: Wow! I'm so pleased you mentioned NeatUpload. I took a copy for myself and it made uploading so easy for me to add to my project. Thanks.

Comment: I get out of memory exception at br.ReadBytes(). File size ~700MB

Answer (score 4):

I know it is an old question, but still unanswered.

So this is what you have to do:

In you web.config file, add this in :

```
    <!-- 3GB Files / in kilobyte (3072*1024) -->
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="3145728"/>
```

and this under

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>

      <!-- 3GB Files / in byte (3072*1024*1024) -->
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3221225472" />

    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

You see in the comment how this works. In one you need to have the sie in bytes and in the other one in kilobytes. Hope that helps.

Comment: But this is not working in my case. can you please elaborate how to make it work. TIA

Answer (score 1):

Try copying without loading every thing in the memory :

```
public void CopyFile()
{
    Stream source = HIF.PostedFile.InputStream; //your source file
    Stream destination = File.OpenWrite(filePath); //your destination
    Copy(source, destination);
}

public static long Copy(Stream from, Stream to)
{
    long copiedByteCount = 0;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[2 << 16];
    for (int len; (len = from.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0; )
    {
        to.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        copiedByteCount += len;
    }
    to.Flush();

    return copiedByteCount;
}
```

Comment: Hello manitra,
I tried using the your functions CopyFile() in client and Copy() in server, but i got some errors.
One more thing i have observed is that WriteAllBytes will work until 3MB of data, more than that it gives "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: There was an exception running the extensions specified in the config file. ---> System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded....." exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx) about large file uploads. It also has a few links to some discussion forums that can shed some light on this as well. The suggestion is to use custom HttpHandler for that or custom Flash/Silverlight control.

Answer (score 0):

For IIS 6.0 you can change AspMaxEntityAllowed in Metabase.xml, but I don't think it's as straight forward in IIS 5.1.

This link may help, hope it does:

http://itonlinesolutions.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=63

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Response.TransmitFile, this method does not load in web server memory the file, it streams the file without using web server resources.

```
if (Controller.ValidateFileExist())
        {
            ClearFields();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "FileNAme.Ext"));
            Response.TransmitFile(FileNAme.Ext);
            Response.End();
            Controller.DeleteFile();
        }
```

Comment: Do not open file in memory, you will take down the server!! 

With all respect, all other solutions posted seems to work with small files, but not with 1Gig files

Comment: This method can be used backwards, for download or upload large files, let me see if I can find the docs

Answer (score 0):

Setting maxRequestLength should be enough for uploading files larger than 4mb, which is the default limit for HTTP request size. Please make extra sure that nothing is overriding your config file.

Alternatively you can check the [async upload provided by Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx), which uploads files by 2mb chunks and effectively can bypass the ASP.NET request size limitation.