# File upload of 390 mb in asp.net 1.1

Tags: asp.net

i want to edit a project already done in asp.net framework 1.1.How to upload a file of size 390 mb in asp.net 1.1 with IIS3? I could upload upto 220 mb by setting maxRequestLength and executionTimeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation i found, the theoretical limit is 4 GB, so i don't see any problem in just changing the values one more time to the size you wish.

Comment: It is showing System.MemoryException again if i tried to upload a file of 280 mb after uploading a file of 390 mb or uploading the same file after renaming.Could you help me? I'm not getting a permanent solution. I got the solution in asp 4.5 by setting maxAllowedContentLength.

Comment: How much hardware memory do you have? IIS is capped at roughly 60% of total machine memory.

Have you considered other posibilities like insted of loading the file in to memory and then save it, you could send it in small packages to the harddrive. (Kind of like when you download a file)

Comment: I have 4 Gb memory. Could you specify how i could send it in small packages to the harddrive?

Comment: This question has been asked alot on SO, so try to search arround here for an answer eg.:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599409/upload-large-files1gb-asp-net and http://neatupload.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions. I will try it and let you know if i got it.

Comment: Sir,to send it in small packages to the harddrive,i should write c# code.right?But it is not entering the c# code while im uploading file of size 280 mb. I tried it using break points.Any other thing to be changed in web config?

Comment: Yes, a common analogy is "How do you eat an elephant, one bite at a time" Insted of sending 280mb, you send 4mb, 70 times.

It is dificult to discuss potential bugs in your code, unless im actually able to see it.

Comment: Thank You.I got it by sending it as small packages using byte array.Thanks a lot for your help.